# 特定の行でjoinするSQLクエリの書き方について

Tags: database

2つのテーブルを特定の期間におけるレコードでjoinをしようとしています。
テーブルの仕様は以下です。

table_A

| event_code | reg_time | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's apple |
| orange | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's orange |
| grape | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's grape |
| apple2 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big apple |
| orange | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big orage |
| grape | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big grape |

table_B

| event_code | event_time | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-10 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| orange | 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| grape | 2022-08-30 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| apple2 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| orange | 2022-09-21 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| grape | 2022-09-31 00:00:00 | 0001 |

join後の期待する結果は以下の通りです。
SQLクエリで書けますでしょうか？
joinするtable_A をevent_codeで連結したいのですが、table_Bのevent_timeより過去日での最新日付を持ったevent_codeでjoinさせたいです。

| event_code | event_time | user_id | reg_time | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-10 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's apple |
| orange | 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's orange |
| grape | 2022-08-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's grape |
| apple2 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big apple |
| orange | 2022-09-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big orage |
| grape | 2022-09-31 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big grape |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> joinするtable_A をevent_codeで連結したいのですが、table_Bのevent_timeより過去日での最新日付を持ったevent_codeでjoinさせたいです。

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/285FUJ2SMuTFFxW3K5D1MB/1)

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_A 
    (event_code  VARCHAR(10),
     reg_time    DATETIME,
     description VARCHAR(15));

INSERT INTO table_A
VALUES
  ('apple',  '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s apple'),
  ('orange', '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s orange'),
  ('grape',  '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s grape'),
  ('apple2', '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big apple'),
  ('orange', '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big orage'),
  ('grape',  '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big grape');

CREATE TABLE table_B
    (event_code VARCHAR(10),
     event_time DATETIME,
     user_id    VARCHAR(5));

INSERT INTO table_B
VALUES
  ('apple',  '2022-08-10 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-08-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-08-30 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('apple2', '2022-09-11 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-09-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-09-30 00:00:00', '0001');


SELECT table_B.event_code, event_time, user_id, reg_time, description
FROM table_B INNER JOIN table_A
ON table_B.event_code = table_A.event_code AND
   reg_time =
     (SELECT MAX(reg_time) FROM table_A WHERE reg_time < event_time);
```

| event_code | event_time | user_id | reg_time | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-10 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's apple |
| orange | 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's orange |
| grape | 2022-08-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's grape |
| apple2 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big apple |
| orange | 2022-09-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big orage |
| grape | 2022-09-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big grape |

Comment: データが追加された場合、別のクエリはありますでしょうか？具体的なデータは別途質問を立てました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/96884/%e7%89%b9%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%ae%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%a7join%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%82%af%e3%82%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a62