# クエリについて2

Tags: sql

2つのテーブルを特定の期間におけるレコードでjoinをしようとしています。
joinするtable_A をevent_codeで連結したいのですが、table_Bのevent_timeより過去日での最新日付を持ったevent_codeでjoinさせたいです。

テーブルの仕様は以下です。

table_A

| event_code | reg_time | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's apple |
| orange | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's orange |
| grape | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's grape |
| apple2 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big apple |
| orange | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big orage |
| grape | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big grape |
| ice | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | big ice |

table_B

| event_code | event_time | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-10 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| orange | 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| grape | 2022-08-30 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| apple2 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| orange | 2022-09-21 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| grape | 2022-09-31 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| apple2 | 2022-10-11 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| ice | 2022-10-15 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| orange | 2022-10-21 00:00:00 | 0001 |
| grape | 2022-10-30 00:00:00 | 0001 |

join後の期待する結果は以下の通りです。
SQLクエリで書けますでしょうか？

| event_code | event_time | user_id | reg_time | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-10 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's apple |
| orange | 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's orange |
| grape | 2022-08-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | it's grape |
| apple2 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big apple |
| orange | 2022-09-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big orage |
| grape | 2022-09-31 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big grape |
| apple2 | 2022-10-11 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big apple |
| ice | 2022-10-15 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 | big ice |
| orage | 2022-10-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big orange |
| grape | 2022-10-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 | big grape |

テーブル作成のコードは以下の通りです。

```
CREATE or replace TABLE table_A 
    (event_code  VARCHAR(10),
     reg_time    DATETIME,
     description VARCHAR(15));

INSERT INTO table_A
VALUES
  ('apple',  '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s apple'),
  ('orange', '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s orange'),
  ('grape',  '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s grape'),
  ('apple2', '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big apple'),
  ('orange', '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big orage'),
  ('grape',  '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big grape'),
  ('ice',  '2022-10-01 00:00:00', 'big ice');

CREATE or replace TABLE table_B
    (event_code VARCHAR(10),
     event_time DATETIME,
     user_id    VARCHAR(5));

INSERT INTO table_B
VALUES
  ('apple',  '2022-08-10 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-08-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-08-30 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('apple2', '2022-09-11 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-09-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-09-30 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('apple2', '2022-10-11 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('ice',  '2022-10-15 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-10-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-10-30 00:00:00', '0001'),
;
```

Comment: タグは質問の範囲を絞り込むために使うものなので、複数製品を同時に指定するのはあまり良い使い方ではありません。「環境に左右されず」であればひとまず `sql` タグで十分です。

Comment: sqlは標準がとても弱く、データベースに依存する傾向がとても強いです。想定しているデータベースのタグは「必ず」付けてください。ただし書く際には速度や書きやすさや慣習などに依りますが、SQL標準に合わせた方が良いです。

Comment: タグが付いている `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server` にはいずれも `CREATE or replace TABLE ...` という構文はなさそう？

Comment: 次の投稿はあなたの質問の回答になりますか？ [特定の行でjoinするSQLクエリの書き方について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/96734/%e7%89%b9%e5%ae%9a%e3%81%ae%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%a7join%e3%81%99%e3%82%8bsql%e3%82%af%e3%82%a8%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ae%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8d%e6%96%b9%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

payanecoさんのDDL/初期データを使用したMySQL8.0.27での別解です。

```sql
select
  B.event_code,
  B.event_time,
  B.user_id,
  A1.reg_time
from
  table_A as A1
  inner join table_B as B
    on A1.event_code=B.event_code
    and A1.reg_time<B.event_time
  left join table_A as A2
    on A2.event_code=B.event_code
    and A2.reg_time<B.event_time
    and A2.reg_time>A1.reg_time -- A1.regtimeが最大のときこの条件を満たすA2レコードはない
where
  A2.event_code is NULL
;
```

Answer (score 1):

where句の副問い合わせを使って、table_Aのreg_timeをtable_Bのevent_timeより過去日での最新日付に限定することで実現できます。

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table_A
    (event_code  VARCHAR(10),
     reg_time    DATETIME,
     description VARCHAR(15));

INSERT INTO table_A
VALUES
  ('apple',  '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s apple'),
  ('orange', '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s orange'),
  ('grape',  '2022-08-01 00:00:00', 'it''s grape'),
  ('apple2', '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big apple'),
  ('orange', '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big orage'),
  ('grape',  '2022-09-01 00:00:00', 'big grape'),
  ('ice',  '2022-10-01 00:00:00', 'big ice');

CREATE TABLE table_B
    (event_code VARCHAR(10),
     event_time DATETIME,
     user_id    VARCHAR(5));

INSERT INTO table_B
VALUES
  ('apple',  '2022-08-10 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-08-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-08-30 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('apple2', '2022-09-11 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-09-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-09-30 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('apple2', '2022-10-11 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('ice',  '2022-10-15 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('orange', '2022-10-21 00:00:00', '0001'),
  ('grape',  '2022-10-30 00:00:00', '0001');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select B.event_code,
       B.event_time,
       B.user_id,
       A.reg_time
from   table_A as A,table_B as B
where  A.event_code = B.event_code
and    A.reg_time   = (select max(A2.reg_time)
                       from   table_A as A2
                       where  A2.event_code = B.event_code
                       and    A2.reg_time < B.event_time);
```

| event_code | event_time | user_id | reg_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2022-08-10 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |
| orange | 2022-08-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |
| grape | 2022-08-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-08-01 00:00:00 |
| apple2 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 |
| orange | 2022-09-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 |
| grape | 2022-09-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 |
| apple2 | 2022-10-11 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 |
| ice | 2022-10-15 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-10-01 00:00:00 |
| orange | 2022-10-21 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 |
| grape | 2022-10-30 00:00:00 | 0001 | 2022-09-01 00:00:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oAqMHAgF3LdPdrecjEeMYb/0)

Comment: schemaと書くなら、DDLまでの方が良いです。